# CentOS and Clustering

Tags: linux, centos, cluster

I'am searching a way to create a cluster of servers based on some rules making it cheking if http, https and custom ports are locally serving request and the same for other remote machines, and if this is possibly, send a vote (token) to the rest of machines, and if not, shutdown himself (STONITH), and the others, when detects the faulty server, execute a custom script if the quorum is enough.

I have search and seems Corosync, keepalive and pacemaker are good approaches, but i can't find the correct way to do what i need.
Any ideas?

Comment: seems you have tried nothing, so technically your are not facing any problem yet.

Comment: Seems overly-complex for standard web services - I'd be tempted to just have 2 or more standard web servers with a load-balancer or two in front, scales better.

Comment: but it sounds like he wants to do more than standard web services

Comment: I know that is far old.
But now, I know what i need for this propose, an auto registry like Consul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clusters are built for a specific purpose. Either to provide higher capacity, fault tolerance or both. 
Most people with web clusters will have loadbalancers out in front of the http servers to distribute traffic to the machines that are up and not too loaded. Behind the http servers is usually database servers configured as active/active or active/passive for fault tolerance.
There are a plethora of ways to do it. Just find one that makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the Answer, but finally i found what i need. Consul.
Maybe it helps to other people in the same situation.